# How to get argument type from type of boost::bind(c++11 NOT available)

Tags: c++, boost

I am wring a generic class to extract something of type SrcT by a string key, convert it to type TargetT and then return. Like:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  bool get(const char* key, std::string& str)
  {
    if (std::string(key) == "found")
    {
        str = "stringA";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  bool get(const char* key, int& a)
  {
    a = 100;
    return true;
  }
};

class Bar
{
public:
  template <typename Converter>
  typename Converter::result_type extract(const char* key, Converter converter)
  {
    typedef typename Converter::first_argument_type SrcT;  // <- HERE IS THE ERROR
    typedef typename Converter::result_type TargetT;
    SrcT temp;
    if (_foo.get(key, temp)) 
    {
      TargetT target = converter(temp);
      return target;
    }
    else
    {
      throw std::runtime_exception("ah");
    }
  }

  Foo _foo;
};

struct Converters
{
  static int toInt(const std::string& str) { return str.size(); }
  static float toFloat(int a) { return 100.0 + a; }
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Nothing)
{
  Bar bar;
  const int saveHere = bar.extract("found", boost::bind(&Converters::toInt, _1));
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(saveHere, 7); // 7=sizeof("stringA")
}
```

TargetT was deduced from Converter type, but no clue about SrcT.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
After checking boost/bind.hpp and boost/bind/bind_template.hpp, looks like no such thing was exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
typedef typename boost::function_traits<Converter>::arg1_type SrcT;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. error: no type named ‘arg1_type’ in ‘struct boost::function_traits<boost::_bi::bind_t<int, int (*)(const std::basic_string<char>&), boost::_bi::list1<boost::arg<1> > > >’
     typedef typename boost::function_traits<Converter>::arg1_type SrcT;